# I am trying to run the following array method using ruby but keep getting the following error:

Tags: ruby, rubymine-7

```
arr = [2,4,6,8]
i = 0
while i < arr.length do
  puts arr[i + 1] - arr[i]
  i = i + 1
end
```

It puts out the values on the console but also issues an error

> ERROR (on RubyMine 7): C:\Ruby21\bin\ruby.exe -e
>   $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift)
>   C:/.../file/application.rb 
>   2  2  2
>   C:/Users/inoor/RubymineProjects/file/application.rb:4:in `<top
>   (required)>': undefined method`-' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
>     from -e:1:in `load'     from -e:1:in`'
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Can someone please help me understand what's going on?

Comment: when `i` becomes 3, what's going to happen?

Comment: When `i = 3` your return value for `arr[i + 1]` is `nil`.  You can't subtract from `nil`.

Comment: AHA! thanks, I'm very much a noobie at this as you can already tell. I am learning though and it's a lot of fun.

Comment: When in doubt play computer and step the code out on paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you see the `nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)` error in ruby you should look for whatever objects could have become `nil`. In your case, you are iterating over an array and are hitting an edge case.

Let's look at your code in detail:

```
# Start with this array of length 4
arr = [2,4,6,8]
# Initilize counter to 0
i = 0
# Run this loop while i < 4
while i < arr.length do
  puts arr[i + 1] - arr[i]
  # Increment by 1 each time
  i = i + 1
end
```

The case you are running into the `nil` object is at the very end. When `i=3`, `i+1=4` and you are trying to access the index 4 element in your array. Remember, arrays in ruby (like most languages) are 0-indexed. So your array has indexes 0,1,2, and 3. If you attempt to access an index that you haven't defined a value for, ruby will return `nil`. So `arr[4]`,`arr[400]`, and `arr[100000000]` all return the same thing: `nil`.